# Handling exceptions using AWS SNS Topic and AWS SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have implemented an event driven architecture application which has around 7 spring boot microservices. As part of the happy flow,these microservices listen to AWS SQS(suppose app_queue) which is subscribed to AWS SNS topic(suppose app_topic).

For exception scenarios we have implemented something like below:

1. Categorised the exceptions as 500(int server errors) and 400(bad req) category errors
2. In both these scenarios, we are dropping a message to the SNS topic named status_topic. A SQS named status_queue is subscribed to this topic. We did this with a view in mind that once the end to end application development is done for happy scenarios, we will handle the messages in the status_queue in such a way that Production support team has a way to remediate both 500 or 400 errors.
   SO basically : app_topic --> app_queue --> Microservice Error --> status_topic --> status_sqs

Needed some expert advice on the below approach if there would be any issues:

1. A k8s cron job(Spring boot microservice) would come up every night to handle the error messages from the above status_queue and handle only 500 int server errors FOR RETRY.
2. The cron job will push the messages back to the normal SNS app_topic which will retrigger the message and normal business flow will continue.
   Is the above mentioned approach acceptable??

I know that DLQs are more suitable for such scenarios, but can I drop a message to a DLQ directly from my java app code?

Regardless of any approach we take, is there a way to automatially replay messages from a specific queue(normal and dlq) so we dont have to write a seperate microservice to replay messages?

Comment: "is there a way to automatically replay messages" - you could setup lambda to do this. This way you don't need any specific microservice k8s to pull the messages from queue.

Comment: Can we setup lambdas for Dead letter queues as well?

Comment: Yes, DLQ are just normal queue. You can even create a DLQ for a DLQ.

Comment: From what I know, messages can be sent to a AWS sqs either from a AWS SNS topic and from another queue to a dlq(if it has a DLQ configured for it). Can we push messages from a microservice to a AWS sqs queue directly?  Also if I use lambdas can we schedule them to run at a specific time in the day?

Comment: After more analysis, I implemented a CloudWatch Events Rule That Triggers on a Schedule. This event rule has a target which is where I configured AWS lambda function which can read messages from the DLQ and take necessary action. I have implemented the Cloudwatch Events Rule and Lambda using terraform.However to get a feel of things you can directly refer this url https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html and do a POC before implementing the actual code